# No Data Returned from USB device

Tags: android, usb

We have a vendor specific Blood pressure device that we want to configure via an Android handy
and it's USB port. 
In addition I have written code for the Windows (handling per WinUSB) that communicates with the
device and as far as I have seen the Android and WinUSB api (of course) have quite some
similarities and it should work quite well. I'm also able to open the device on Android
and fetching the endpoints (bulk endpoints). The device supports interrupt and bulk read/write endpoints.

I'm also able to successfully write a command via controlTransfer to the device e.g.

```
   private void tryGetDescriptor() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[18];

        // https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb6.shtml#SetupPacket standard device requests
        int retVal = m_devCon.controlTransfer(0x80, 0x06, 0x0100, 0, buffer, 0x12, TIMEOUT);

        if(retVal < 0) {
            Debug("something failed");
        } else {
            Debug( "check buffer " + String.valueOf( retVal ) + " arr: " + Arrays.toString(buffer) );
        }
    }
```

or the one controlTransfer that my reference code in Delphi does:

```
   private void startPeripheral() {
        int retVal = m_devCon.controlTransfer(0x40, 2, 0, m_readPkgSize, null, 0, 0);
        if(retVal < 0) {
            Debug("StartPeripheral failed!");
        } else {
            Debug("Control Transfer returned " + String.valueOf(retVal));
        }
    }
```

I'm now facing the problem that according to the write endpoint I may send a command to the device
but I don't get a return back (the device should at least echo the command)

here the thread that handles that (I know the sync stuff is not actually Java like so please be
patient with me...)

```
        private UsbDeviceConnection m_devCon;
        private UsbEndpoint m_epRead;
        private UsbEndpoint m_epWrite;
        private String m_command = "";
        private boolean terminated = false;

        public void sigTerminate(){
            terminated = true;
            m_command = "";
        }

        public void init( UsbDeviceConnection devCon, UsbEndpoint readEP, UsbEndpoint writeEP ) {
            this.m_devCon = devCon;
            this.m_epRead = readEP;
            this.m_epWrite = writeEP;
        }

        public void asyncSendCmd( String cmd ) {
            Debug("AsyncSendCmd: " + cmd);
            m_command = new String(cmd);
        }


        private void sendRec() {
            Debug("Run thread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[m_readPkgSize];

            try {

                 //while( req.queue( rBuf ) ) {
                 while (true) {
                     try {

                         while (m_command == "" && !terminated)
                             sleep(10);

                         Debug("Something found" + m_command);
                     } catch (InterruptedException f) {
                         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                         Debug("Thread interruped: " + f.getMessage());
                     }
                     String cpyCmd = new String(BR102_RESET );
                     m_command = "";

                     if (!terminated && isConnected()) {
                         // not threadsave but what shels
                         Debug("Writing command: " + cpyCmd);
                         byte[] writeBuf = cpyCmd.getBytes();

                         //int lenWrite = m_devCon.bulkTransfer(m_epWrite, writeBuf, writeBuf.length, TIMEOUT);

                         //if (lenWrite != writeBuf.length)
                         //    throw new IOException("Write failed with len: " + String.valueOf(lenWrite));


                         // sleep(48);

                         UsbRequest wreq = new UsbRequest();
                         wreq.initialize( m_devCon, m_epWrite);
                         ByteBuffer wBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(writeBuf);
                         wreq.queue( wBuf );

                         final UsbRequest responsew = m_devCon.requestWait( TIMEOUT );
                         if(responsew == null) {
                             Debug("no write response");
                             break;
                         }

                         int lenWrite = wBuf.position();
                         Debug("Wrote: " + String.valueOf(lenWrite));

                         wreq.close();



                         UsbRequest req = new UsbRequest();
                         req.initialize(m_devCon, m_epRead);

                         ByteBuffer rBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap( buffer );
                         req.queue( rBuf );

                         //int lenRead = m_devCon.bulkTransfer(m_epRead, buffer, m_readPkgSize, TIMEOUT);


                         final UsbRequest response = m_devCon.requestWait(TIMEOUT);
                         if(response == null) {
                             Debug("No Resonse");
                             break;
                         }

                         int lenRead = rBuf.position();
                         if (lenRead > 0) Debug("lenRead: " + String.valueOf(lenRead));
                         else Debug("lenRead: " + String.valueOf(lenRead));

                         req.close();

                     }
                     //rBuf.rewind();
                     //req.close();
                 }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Debug("Error in usb read thread: " + e.toString());// e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendRec();
        }
    }
```

As one can see I tried a quite few things. And that's the most complicated one I came up. Basically
my first try was more or less bulkTransfers which behave the same...

Note that the "Reset\n" command can be sent 2 times and then even the writes fail...

for the sake of completeness here is the usb initialization routine:

```
   private void startUSB(UsbDevice device) throws IllegalArgumentException  {
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        if(!usbManager.hasPermission( device )) {
            usbManager.requestPermission( device, m_permissionIntent );
            return;

        }
        try {
            if( usbReader != null) {
                Debug("WTF usbReader already started!!!!");

                usbReader.sigTerminate();
                usbReader.join();
                usbReader = null;
            }
            // ########################################################
            // #### we the permission -> get the interfaces and check for the endpoints
            m_device = device;
            int numInterfaces = m_device.getInterfaceCount();
            if(numInterfaces > 0) {
                Debug("Number of interfaces: " + String.valueOf(numInterfaces));

                m_devIntf = m_device.getInterface(0);

                Debug(String.valueOf(m_devIntf.getInterfaceProtocol()));

                Debug("Number of endpoints: " + m_devIntf.getEndpointCount());
                m_epRead = null;
                m_epWrite = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < m_devIntf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
                    UsbEndpoint endPoint = m_devIntf.getEndpoint(i);

                    Debug(String.valueOf(i + 1) + ": Endpoint " + endPoint.toString());

                    if (endPoint.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN && endPoint.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                        m_epRead = endPoint;
                    }
                    if (endPoint.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT && endPoint.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                        m_epWrite = endPoint;
                    }
                }

                if (m_epRead == null || m_epWrite == null)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No bulk read or write endpoint found");

                Debug("Got endpoints");
                // ############################################################################
                // okidoki we have endpoints and we have an interface -> open the device
                m_devCon = usbManager.openDevice(m_device);
                Debug("Got device");
                if (m_devCon == null)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Deviceconnection?!");
                if (!m_devCon.claimInterface(m_devIntf, false))
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Claim failed");

                Debug("All fine - now we can start the conversation");
                m_readPkgSize = m_epRead.getMaxPacketSize();
                m_writePkgSize = m_epWrite.getMaxPacketSize();

                tryGetDescriptor();

                // ############################################################################
                // ### init reading and wrinting
                usbReader = new UsbReadThread();
                usbReader.init( m_devCon, m_epRead, m_epWrite );
                usbReader.start();



                startPeripheral();
            } else {
                Debug("No interfaces");
            }
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug( "Device connection failed with " + e.getMessage() );
            // release
            closeUSB();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys - after I had a chance to look at the firmware I finally recognized that - even though 4 usb endpoints are published - I may only write on the Interrupt pipe endpoint and only read from the bulktransfer endpoint.